# Group By Localized Date

Tags: mysql

Tracking the total sales by day based on a table of transactions is quite easy to write.  The current code uses a `BETWEEN` and executes a query **for each date**.  I don't really like this, especially when date ranges are in months.

Now, the `date_created` field for the transaction is of the type `timestamp`. And writing a query like works, except for one thing:

```
SELECT DATE(date_created), sum(sale_total)
FROM
    transaction
WHERE DATE(date_created) BETWEEN ? and ?
GROUP BY DATE(date_created)
```

It works beautifully, except that the database is localized to [GMT](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/), and I'm here in [CST](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/usa/central-time/).  So any transactions that occur after 7:00 PM [CST](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/usa/central-time/) will be "pushed" to the next day because it is stored as the next day in [GMT](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/).

**I guess my question is 2-fold**

- How would I proceed to `GROUP BY` the localized date?
- Is there a way strictly in MySQL know that I want to use a different timezone in the query?  Or will this have to be a manual adjustment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP` fields are stored as UTC under the hood. If your data is in `TIMESTAMP` fields, you can set the MySQL time zone to use: `SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';`

If you've stored the data in `DATETIME` fields, they get stored in the MySQL system time zone, so conversion would be on you.